# Adding a welcome message once app opens

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I am trying to display a welcome message when the user launches the app. I am using the `UIAlertController` class.

I am adding the `UIAlertController` in app delegate, here it is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc] init]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIAlertController *alertMessage = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome!", @"Welcome")
                                                                          message:@"Enjoy Using the Browser"
                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    return YES;
}
```

I get the warning that `alertMessage` is not being used. I don't know how to go forward, any hints or tips?

Comment: You have to present the alert. Read the docs for `UIAlertController` to see how.

Comment: Where is your code to present the UIAlertController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a best practice to show a `UIAlertController` from `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.  You have two options.

1. Present the alert controller on the first view controller you load.
2. Present the alert controller on the window's root view controller.

Either way, you're going to want to call `[someViewController presentViewController:alertMessage animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

You can try alert view

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome!", @"Welcome")
                                                 message:@"Enjoy Using the Browser"
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
return YES;
```

Comment: Since `UIAlertView` was deprecate in iOS 8 and iOS 9 is out tomorrow, it's probably best to stick with `UIAlertController`.

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated now. We should try using UIAlertController as much as possible. I believe the answer posted by JAL makes more sense from this point of view.